# Compiler Error 'User defined type not defined'

Tags: vba, excel-2016

The following statement

```
Dim NewFrame As MSForms.Frame
```

is giving compile time error:

> 'User defined type not defined'.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Can you share the code where NewFrame is defined?

Comment: fwiw, i found your answer inside 30 seconds by searching for **MSForms in 2016**.

Answer (score 1):

To access the methods, properties and members of a MSForms object, go to the VBE's Tools, References and put a check mark beside  “Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library” (or similar for your version). This will link the FM20.DLL (or similar for your version) from your O/S's system32 folder.

Comment: Yet if using forms it is automatically added ...

Comment: Is that true for xl2016? i found some interesting information within the Q&A i marked as duplicate.

Comment: Don't know. Will NEVER use 2016.

Comment: Everytime I open workbook , I have to manually add FM20.dll. Is there any way by which I can permanently add the .dll ?